# Issue in sorting SML list

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am new to SML.I got this sorting algo to implement where in each iteration,I have to pick minimum element from the list, remove it and create sorted list.

I did below coding to solve the problem.

I wrote 2 helper functions to pickup minimum element from the list and remove one element from the list.

```
fun minList(x::xs) =List.foldl (fn (x,y)=> if x<y then x else y) x (x::xs);

fun remElem(x, l) =
   case l of
   [] => []
 | (x1::x2::xs) => if x1=x then (x2::xs) else (x1::xs)
;
```

Above two programs ran successfully.

Below is my sorting code.

```
fun simpSort(xs)=
let fun aux(xs,acc)=
       case xs of
            [] =>acc
           | [x] => [x]
            | (x::xs) => let val m = minList(xs) 
                       in
                     aux(remElem(m,xs),acc@[m])
                       end
in aux(xs,[])
end;
```

This sorting program is giving error.

- simpSort([3,1]);

  uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
  raised at: stdIn:433.59

Please advise.

Comment: `remElem` only handles the empty list and lists with at least two elements.

Comment: Also, `remElem` removes either the first or the second element of the list, and nothing else. That's probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thanks. When I do this code - fun remElem (i, xs) =
    case xs of
    []=>[]
      | x::xs => if i = x then remElem(i,xs)
          else x::remElem(i,xs)     It is deleting all occurences of the input char where I want to delete only the first occurence.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough; you're removing the first element if it is the first occurrence, otherwise you're removing the second element – regardless of what that second element is. For instance, `remElem(97, [1,2,97])` will produce `[1,97]`, and so will `remElem(12, [1,2,97])`.

Comment: Thanks.I modified the remElem program.It is now  fun remElem(x, l) =
    case l of
    [] => []
  | [x] => []
  | (x1::xs) => if x1=x then (xs) else x1::remElem(x,xs)
 ;   It is giving proper output. But sorting function SimpSort is still giving erroneous result.

Comment: I managed to fix it.I noticed I was not passing arguments properly in helper functions.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've solved your problem, here are some hints for improving a working version of your code:

- Find the minimum of a list in a way that supports empty lists:

  ```
  fun minimum [] = NONE
    | minimum (x::xs) = SOME (foldl Int.min x xs)
  ```
- Simplify pattern matching in the function that removes the first occurrence of an element from a list:

  ```
  fun remove (_, []) = []
    | remove (y, x::xs) =
      if x = y
      then xs
      else x :: remove (y, xs)
  ```
- Use those in combination to write `simpSort`:

  ```
  fun simpSort xs =
      case minimum xs of
           NONE => []
         | SOME x => x :: simpSort (remove (x, xs))
  ```

I shouldn't have to say that this sorting algorithm is terribly inefficient. :-P